# Combine Simple HTML Dom with JSON data I have no idea

Tags: php, ajax, dom, simple-html-dom

I received json datas with the ajax post method.

The sample format what I receiving from `tomorrow.php`:

> POSTDATA=country=America&competition=Copa+Libertado&team=Boca+Juniors , content type = application/json, charset utf-8 ) via tomorrow.php at my simple html dom query file. I receive multiple json datas, so not just one POSTDATA.

I would like to convert all datas to php variables. How can I do this? And How can I combine with my existing `simple_html_dom` query?

My existing simple html dom query (I included tomorrow.php which send the json datas with county, competition, and club):

```
 <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    ini_set("user_agent", "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17");

    include ("tomorrow.php");
    include ("mysql.php");
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

        $filename = "footballfixtures.html";
        $html = file_get_html($filename);

    class matches {
        var $day;
        var $kickofftime;
        var $title;

            function matches ($day, $kickofftime, $title){
                    $this->day=$day;
            $this->kickofftime=$kickofftime;
                    $this->title=$title;
                    return $this;
        }
    }

    $i=0;

    $day=$html->find('h1',0);
    $day->plaintext;
    $day=str_replace("<h1>TODAY FOOTBALL FIXTURES: ","", $day);
    $day=str_replace("</h1>","", $day);
    $matchday = str_replace(array('MONDAY ', 'TUESDAY ', 'WEDNESDAY ', 'THURSDAY ', 'FRIDAY ',  'SATURDAY ',  'SUNDAY '), '', $day);
    $matchday=str_replace(" ","-", $matchday);
    $matchday=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($matchday));

    foreach($html->find('table.fixtures') as $matches) 
    {
        foreach ($matches->find('tr[class=a1],tr[class=a2]') as $matchesTR) {

        $kickofftime=$matchesTR->find('td[matches]',0)->plaintext;
        $kodate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$matchday $kickofftime +1 hour"));
        $title=$matchesTR->find('pre[class=title]',0)->plaintext;


        $i++;


        $title = ucwords(strtolower($title));

        echo $kodate;
        echo $title;


       }
    }

    // clean up memory
        $html->clear();
        unset($html);

    ?>
```

I would like to combine the datas what I received from `footballfixtures.html` (kickoff time and title) plus what I received via the json datas (via tomorrow.php).

I would like these result in every row:

kodate, title, competition, country, team

I hope somebody can help for me because I have no idea.

Comment: Please note that the data you posted is **not** JSON but rather `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data

Comment: Host=localhost User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0 Accept=application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01 Accept-Language=en_EN,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8 X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest Referer=localhost/football/process.php Content-Length=61 Connection=keep-alive Pragma=no-cache Cache-Control=no-cache POSTDATA=country=America&competition=Copa+Libertado&club=Boca+Juniors Details at Tamper Data